# ScrollView + Programmatic View addition = No Scroll

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I can't say I've had this problem before, maybe I just need a fresh pair of eyes.  After adding views programatically to a LinearLayout inside the root ScrollView, the ScrollView doesn't seem to know and doesn't scroll.

In the following, `group` is an extension of LinearLayout and `root` is the LinearLayout inside the XML layout.

My main XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_root"
    style="@style/Standard.Fill" <!-- match_parent in both _width and _height -->
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_group"
        style="@style/BaseGroup" <!-- derived style from Standard.Fill -->
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

Adding views, for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 95; i++){
    TextView kv = new TextView(this);
    kv.setText("asdas as adsa");

    // kvp is LayoutParams with match_parent and wrap_content
    group.addView(kv, kvp); 
}
root.addView(group, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The ScrollView parent doesn't seem to know it's LinearLayout child has expanded past the bounds and doesn't scroll.  I've tried variations of `fillViewport`, `layout_width` and `layout_height`, `requestLayout()`, `invalidate()`, etc to no avail.

I'm probably going to switch over to a `ListView` and the adapter workflow, but this is still very strange to me.

How can I get my ScrollView parent to wake up?

Comment: Do any Views inside have click or touch listeners? Or do the accept focus (`focusable="true"`)?

Comment: Negative. They're basic custom views. Thought there was something wrong because of that, but the same behavior occurs with standard TextViews as well.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: @lpfx sorry mate. It's been years since I touched android. I don't recall.